# Recursive submodule checkout on every branch switch

Tags: git, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to make SourceTree not do a recursive submodule checkout when switching between branches?
Even though the original checkout was done without submodule recursion, a branch switch always does this:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false submodule update --init --recursive
```

[atlassian community thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Recursive-submodule-checkout-on-every-branch-switch/qaq-p/211723)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet (no option available in SourceTree itself)

One possible workaround (and it *is* just a workaround) would be to do the checkout in command line, then switch back to SourceTree and refresh the working tree.

Comment: thanks, so  is that  your solution at work or just use other git client ?

Comment: @XiangHu No, you don't have to use another Git client: I do use SourceTree at work.